# Subversion sudo svn update changes file ownership and rwx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, version-control, permissions

I'm limiting permissions on a certain file, `settings.py` in my svn-linked directory so that it can only be read by sudo users and apache, which goes by the username, `www-data`. So, on settings.py, I've set `sudo chmod 640 settings.py` and `sudo chown www-data:www-data settings.py`. I still want my unprivileged users to be able to `svn update` and `svn commit`, so with `sudo visudo`, I've set

```
unprivileged_user ALL = /usr/bin/svn commit *, /usr/bin/svn update *, \
                        /usr/bin/svn update
```

so that this user can still do `sudo svn commit` and `sudo svn update`. It won't be able to do plain `svn commit` or `svn update` because of the limited permissions on `settings.py`. If the unprivileged user tries to do that, there will be a message from svn that says the working copy is locked. I've noticed however that when I do `sudo svn update`, the unprivileged_user is updating as root and as a result the file that are updated from the svn repository are now owned by `root:root` with `644` privileges. This goes against what I'm trying to with making `settings.py` owned by `www-data:www-data`. What can I do to make it so that `www-data` is always the owner and the rwx prvileges remain the same?

Comment: I think the root of the problem here is that you are trying to keep a file secret from users who are working in the repo it is in. If you can avoid doing this, then you avoid your problems.

Comment: @skyler But that's the main thing I'm trying to do here. But even if I had it separate, whenever I `svn update` svn changes the file ownership and permissions... I think I need to read up on umask and apache's uid.

Comment: The problem is that your permissions don't exist in svn, so you can't change them. Furthermore by allowing anyone to do `sudo svn commit` you have actually just lost all security because someone can use that to spawn an editor as root allowing them to read and write any file on your system.

Comment: `svn commit` spawns an editor to edit commit messages.

Comment: if we're not looking at `svn commit` anymore, how about just figuring out a way to allow `svn update` to happen without changing the owner/permissions?

Comment: What happens when you do `svn update` while the file has 640 permissions? If it doesn't fail, then everything should be good.

Comment: Well since it's owned by `www-data` with 640 permissions I can't `svn update` as the unprivileged user, I have to `sudo svn update`.. and that ends up changing the owner and group to `root`.

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do this inside svn. However, you could replace `settings.py` with a symlink inside svn and then have the real `settings.py` somewhere else on your system with the appropriate permissions. Then `svn commit` and `svn update` would work fine and the permissions/owner would never be changed.

Comment: @skyler Please take a look at my answer. I'd like to know what you think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use an script instead which do the update and reset the permission.

**svnupdate.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_PROJ_PATH=/home/.... # Put you path here
pushd $MY_PROJ_PATH
svn update $* && chown -R www-data. . && chmod 640 settings.py
popd
```

also make sure `chmod 750 /usr/local/bin/svnupdate.sh` to prevent security issue on sudo command
and also update the sudoeres files:

```
unprivileged_user ALL = /usr/bin/svn commit *, /usr/local/bin/svnupdate.sh
```

Comment: A determined attacker could break this by aborting `svnupdate.sh` before it executes `chown -R www-data. .`.

Comment: This approach is still unsafe. A user can gain a root shell because they can use `sudo svn commit ...` to open an editor as root then overwrite `/usr/local/bin/svnupdate.sh` to contain just `bash` and then run `sudo /usr/local/bin/svnupdate.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for hint. But satisfy my environment concerns. Hopes my code + your security hints helps OP as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `www-data` user will have a different UID on each system it is on, making it effectively a new user on each system. You cannot predict which user this will be so you cannot set the owner appropriately. Whoever checks it out will be the owner.

Furthermore, svn does not track permissions. It only tracks whether or not a file is executable. The permissions that the file comes with are determined by your umask.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have right now. I'm using a post svn update hook, and I don't know how secure it is. This is for `svn update` only. Please feel free to state your opinions on this.

In `usr/local/bin`, I create `ssh-action.sh` based off of this:
http://top-frog.com/2009/04/23/client-side-pre-and-post-svn-hooks-with-unix-aliases/

My actual `ssh-action.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
REAL_SVN='/usr/bin/svn';
BASE_PATH='/home/unprivileged_user/test_svn/';

$REAL_SVN $@;
wait;

# post-svn actions
if [ $1 = 'up' ] || [ $1 = 'update' ]; then
    find -L $BASE_PATH -type f -name 'settings.py' -exec bash -c 'sudo chmod 0400 $0 && sudo chown www-data $0; sudo chgrp www-data $0' '{}' \;
fi
```

Then in `sudo visudo`, I add this to the bottom:

```
unprivileged_user ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/chown www-data */test_svn/settings.py, /bin/chmod 0400 */test_svn/settings.py, /bin/chgrp www-data */test_svn/settings.py
```

Next, `cd /home/unprivileged_user`, open `.bashrc` , and add this to the bottom:

```
alias svn = /usr/local/bin/ssh-action.sh
```

Afterward, I need to make `.bashrc` immutable so that the unprivileged can't edit it to bypass my svn hook. I do this with `sudo chattr +i .bashrc`

With this hopefully whenever the unprivileged_user tries to `svn update` the `test_svn` working copy, `settings.py` will be owned by `www-data:www-data` with 400 permissions. What do you guys think? Are there any security flaws here? Thanks.

Comment: This is not secure. Your unprivileged can now take ownership of any and every file on your system as follow: `touch "www-data"; sudo /bin/chown www-data --reference myfile.txt /etc/passwd /etc/shadow ./test_svn/settings.py`. As you can see, this matches your rule but by creating a file called www-data I have just taken anything I want. Your approach is getting too complicated and you have locked your users out of their own .bashrc files. You need to think about the problem differently and take a different approach. Why not use symlinks as I suggested earlier?

Comment: I tried your symlinks idea, but when I tried to import variables from the symlink, it didn't work. second command you wrote `sudo /bin/chown www-data --reference myfile.txt /etc/passwd /etc/shadow ./test_svn/settings.py` isn't allowed with the `sudo visudo` rules I have, so maybe I'm okay? Locking users out of their .bashrc files is okay with me. I'll just have to edit it for them later.